# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS after removing view controllers stack

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, modalviewcontroller

I have navigation controller subclass with some view controllers in its stack. Let the last one be LastController. I need to present modal view controller, and i want to get rid of controllers stack which i no longer use.

```
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
self.viewControllers = nil;
```

Then just before modal view controller dismissal i set viewControllers to array with one controller in it (not LastController).

Then when i call  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal.

NSZombies say that 
-[LastController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance.

Where is connection between modal view controller and LastController?